# What is the best verb to use for “calculating check-sum hash” action?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I’m not sure that *“hash”* as a verb, is clear enough in software development because it can be a noun as well. And even if so, it collides with a built-in system function used for the different purpose.

So I need to pick up a verb for the function name that does *“calculating check-sum hash”* but it cannot be *“hash”* itself as it is already occupied.

What would be best (preferably single-worded) verb for such action after *hash* itself as a verb?

Comment: So you don't want to use hash-as-a-verb because of a collision?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using "hash" as a verb, in the computer context.  It's quite common.

Comment: There is “hash” built-in function used for calculating dictionary keys (slightly different purpose) and dealing with a problem by using name-spaces for the one-lined function is too much. I cant find single-worded verb besides more ambiguous *“calculate”* and *“evaluate”* for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of *“calculating check-sum hash”* purpose is to produce the check-sum product that is usually unique to the subject.

Inspired by the terms from the [cryptography world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) that utilizing similar concept (but discarding cryptographic demand for properties like an infeasible recovery of the message from the check-sum nor strong avalanche effect) I find these terms as good synonyms for the *hash* as a verb:

- **Fingerprint**
- **Digest**
- **Derive**

As my primary need is to *derive* a *fingerprint* of a subject using some function to *digest* it.

Answer (score 2):

"Hash" is quite often used as a verb and this is pretty easy to disambiguate by context, although the verb form is often shown in the present progressive tense (i.e. "hashing" as opposed to "hash").

Comment: It is true in general. But there are already **two** functions with the **same name** in the **same context** while their purpose slightly differs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another word, maybe you can use "encode"? Or:

calcChecksum()
and
verifyChecksum() (which actually does the same thing as calcChecksum())

Either process does exactly the same thing. Just sends binary data through the hash function to get a checksum result.

Comment: I don't think "encode" is quite right - that implies that you can *decode* it.

Comment: Calculate checksum is somehow vague as it can be used for verification as well (when *calculating* sum and *checking* them) while verify checksum is actually not the emitting process but a comparison process of the emitted sums.

Comment: @misanthrope At the end of the day when either generating the checksum or checking it against the original you run the binary data through the same hash function, if you want to avoid simply calling hash() in both cases wrap the hash() call in a more descriptive call. Both hashes are the same function, just one's done before and one after transmission to check integrity and security.